# Change XML value with XSLT

Tags: java, xslt

**I have :**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>00.01.00.00</version>
</parent>
```

**What I want**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parameter1</artifactId>
    <version>parameter2</version>
</parent>
```

**So I made a Java GUI where I put my parameters (this is only the button event code)  :**

```
    private void btnModifyActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String strArtifactID = txtArtifactID.toString();
    int iVersion = new Integer(txtVersion.getText());


    Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new File("c:/Users/balestrierih/Desktop/pomReplace.xml"));
    Source xsl = new StreamSource(new File("c:/Users/balestrierih/Desktop/pomReplace.xsl"));
    Result xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new File("c:/Users/balestrierih/Desktop/output.xml"));

    try {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
        transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
    } catch (TransformerException TE) {
        TE.getMessage();
    }

}
```

**it will launch a XSL Code :**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="artifactID">
        <xsl:param name="strArtifactID"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="($strArtificatID)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="version">
        <xsl:param name="iVersion"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="($iVersion)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I launch my programm, I got an error which says that the XSLT code is not correct

Comment: No idea if this is the issue, but you have misspelt `($strArtifactID)` in your XSLT

Comment: Thanks, but it did'nt resolve the problem

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is your xslt transformation failing or you don't know how to get the desired xml output?

Comment: Attach you error message, please.

Comment: @Mr.White Yes, it's my xslt transformation failing, nothing change

Answer (score 0):

I think you need global parameters (assuming you want to set them to values before you run the transformation) and then of course you simply need to put the parameter values into the elements you want to manipulate with XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="strArtifactID"/>
  <xsl:param name="iVersion"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="artifactId">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$strArtifactID"/>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="version">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$iVersion"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now you can set the parameters and the elements named `artifactId` (watch out for spelling differences) and `version` will be populated with the parameter values passed in.

Comment: Thanks, your code look very correct, but I still got any modifications in my output

Comment: Well I showed the XSLT part of the code, of course you need to modify the Java code as well as so far it does not set any parameters, so make sure you do e.g. `transformer.setParameter("strArtifactID", strArtifactID)` in your Java call before calling the `transform` method.

Comment: Done, but nothing change...shouldn't I use a replace method ? like :


   `<xsl:value-of select="replace(somethingToReplace, $strArtifactID)"/>`



instead of


   `<xsl:value-of select="$strArtifactID"/>`